# Asp.net web services and how to reuse a WMI or DB connections?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wmi

I have simple asp.net web service, for monitoring and managing about 10 computers, with 4 webMethods and all of this methods are quite simple.
In general they look sometning like: (1)make WMI connections to certain machine, (2)do some simple task, (3)return result.

Problem is that WMI connections to remote computers takes about 15s and I offten need to call 2 or 3 methods successively for the same machine.

From what I know, there is new instance of my service class (public class MonSvr : System.Web.Services.WebService ) created every time webMethod is called.

- So  how can I share WMI or DB connection betwen all instances of my
  service that I could reuse this connection ?
- When there all multiple calls to
  webMethods of my service, does then
  each instance of web service runs in
  separate thread ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static `Dictionary` containing the name of the remote machine and the WMI connection.  This could then be shared between different calls.  You may have issues with multiple threads using the WMI classes at once, so be sure to check all calls are thread safe.

Comment: How can I create connection on service start, before any of webMethods get called ?

Comment: You might be best to create it the first time it is requested from each call. Then the first is slow, but any further are quick.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't you want to save the cost of object creation? If it is so then why not use Singleton pattern? and for multi-threaded Singleton you can check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: In my case singelton is OK for DB access because there is only one DB. But I don't know about WMI connectins to multiple computers.